# iterate through a lisit which would have range as an element and expand it

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm a newbie to python I want to iterate through a list which might have ranges in it and expand it.

```
def ExpandList(c):
    new_list = []
    for i in c:
        print(i)
        if '-' in i:
            low,high=i.split('-')[0],i.split('-')[-1]
            if low !=high:
                for j in range(low,high):
                    new_list.append(j)
            else:
                new_list.append(low)
        else:
            new_list.append(i)

return new_list
```

c = [1001-1002,1005-1009,1010,1010-1025]

with the above input I want to expand the list.
when I iterate through the given list, it does not take 1001-1002 as the single element unless i mention it as a string '1001-1002'. I cannot force user to give that as string.. 
how do i evaluate this and acheive what i intend to.
kindly advise

Comment: How user enters the range value?

Comment: 1001-1002 gets evaluated to -1. You must force users to pass it as a string, that happens outside the code you've provided.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to ask the user to provide all the values as strings.
Either inputting them by hand to the program or writing them into a text file one per line.
That way no quotes would be necessary.

That said, in python 3.8 you can use the brand new walrus operator in a generator expression and then chain all the ranges

```
import itertools as it

c = ['1001-1002','1005-1009','1010','1010-1025']

cx = (range(int(r[0]), int(r[1])) if len((r:=el.split('-')))>1 else [el] for el in c )

res = it.chain.from_iterable(cx)

print(list(res))
```

produces

```
[1001, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, '1010', 1010, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 1020, 1021, 1022, 1023, 1024]
```

Note: I am passing the upper range limit to `range` as it is. In case it needs to be included, increase it by one

```
range(int(r[0]), int(r[1])+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Hyphen is subtraction operator in python. So, your input will be immediately evaluated to

```
[-1, -4, 1010, -15]
```

So, the only logical way is to have the input as string and then later parse it.